# How to map the picture in my display template to my cusstom picture column?

Tags: list-template

I have a sharepoint 2013 portal. I have added a search result webpart. In this webpart I have selected the control template "List" and the item template "Large Image". There is a option in the settings of the webpart to manage the property mappings. I have set the name of my picture column but I still dont see the picture. Do I miss something?

The image column has this name "Afbeelding".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Managed Property and map the crawled property corresponding to your Site Column to this.

Here are details: http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/03/06/from-site-column-to-managed-property-what-s-up-with-that.aspx.

Basically

1. You need to perform a full crawl after filling in data in your column.
2. Then in the Search Service Application you can go in under Search Schema -> Crawled properties and search for your column name (internal name).
3. You should find a crawled property containing the internal name, but having some other stuff as well, like ows_TEXT etc.
4. Go to the Managed Property section
5. Create a new Managed property, or add to PublishingImage your crawled property (You can see in the configuration of PublishingImage how you should configure a new one if wanted)
6. Perform full crawl
7. Use the Managed property name in your Content by Search WP

Comment: I have followed your steps. I have found the property in step 3. It has the name "AfbeeldingOWSIMGE". What do you mean in step 5? I see already a managed property with this name. Do I need to change some configuration from this property?

Comment: If you already have a Managed property (not crawled) you can use its name directly in the Content by Search Webpart (7)

Comment: Ok, this is the name of my managed property "AfbeeldingOWSIMGE". And this is the name of my crawled property "ows_r_IMGE_Afbeelding". I have added the name of my managed property to my search result webpart. After this I did a full crawl and I still dont see the picture.

Comment: How are the properties sat for this Managed property? Compare it to PublishingImage to make it correct